# JS code for autocomplete while box checked

Tags: javascript, html

We need to enable auto-complete on this form.  Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip. If the checkbox is unchecked, the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.

---

HTML Code

```
<pre>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
        <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipName" id = "shippingName"         required><br/>
        <label for = "shippingZip">Zip code:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipZip" id = "shippingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange= "billingFunction()"/>
    <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>

    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Billing Information</legend>
        <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "billName" id = "billingName" required><br/>
        <label for = "billingZip">Zip code:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "billZip" id = "billingZip" pattern =       "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
    </fieldset>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/>
   </form>
 </pre>
```

JS Code

```
<pre>
function billingFunction(){
 var bn, bz, sn, sz;
 if (document.getElementById('same').checked){
   bn = document.getElementById('billingName').text;
   sn = document.getElementById('shippingName').text;
   bz = document.getElementById('billingZip').text;
   sz = document.getElementById('shippingZip').text;
   bn = sn;
   bz = sz;
   }
 }
 </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function billingFunction(){
 var bn, bz, sn, sz;
 bn = document.getElementById('billingName');
 bz = document.getElementById('billingZip');
 if (document.getElementById('same').checked){
   sn = document.getElementById('shippingName').value;
   sz = document.getElementById('shippingZip').value;
   bn.value = sn;
   bz.value = sz;
 } else {
   bn.value = '';
   bz.value = '';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery you can simplify the function like this.

```
$('#same').change(function(){
 var name, zip;
 if ($('#same').prop('checked')){
   name = $('#shippingName').val();
   zip = $('#shippingZip').val();
 }
 $('#billingName').val(name);
 $('#billingZip').val(zip);     
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't use JQuery yet. but, I did simplify it by removing the variables and make just 2 equations.